# Jquery : how to know which row is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with dynamically changing rows items.

Among the rows there is a small button / link for each unit.

Eg

```
   Data1 | LinkButton
   Data2 | LinkButton
   Data3 | LinkButton 
   Data4 | LinkButton
   Data5 | LinkButton 
   Data6 | LinkButton
```

What i want is that when i click on the link button ,i need to know which row is selected?Can any one give me pointers on how that can be done?

You help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body><center>
        <div id="message" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="waiting" style="display: none;">
            Please wait<br />
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loader" alt="Loader" />
        </div>
        <form action=""  id="searchForm">
            <label for="search">Matter Search:</label> <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </form>

        <div id="matterTableDiv"  style="display: none;">
            List of Matters
            <table id="matterTable"   border="1">
                <thead>
                <th>Matter Names</th>
                <th>Matter Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="matterDetailTableDiv" style="display: none;">
            Matter Detail Table
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){


                $('#search').focus();

                $('#submit').click(function(){



                    $('#message').hide(200);
                    $("#matterTableDiv").hide(200);
                    $("#matterTable tbody").text("");
                    $('#waiting').show(200);
                    $('#searchForm').hide(200);
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : 'post.php',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data: {
                            search : $('#search').val()
                        },
                        success : function(data){
                            if(data.msg == "[]" ){
                                $('#waiting').hide(200);
                                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                .text('There was an error.').show(200);
                                $('#searchForm').show(200);

                            }

                            $('#waiting').hide(200);
                            $('#matterTableDiv').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                            if(data.error == false){

                                var str = JSON.parse(data.msg);
                                $("#matterTableDiv").show(200);
                                //alert("List :" + str.length);
                                //alert("List :" + str.toString());
                                $("#matterTable").html();

                                $.each(str, function(key, value) {
                                    var tblRow =
                                        "<tr>"
                                        //+"<td><a id="+key+" href='#dbID="+value.dbID+"&matID="+value.matterID+">"+value.matterInfoSortName+"</a></td>"
                                        +"<td>"+value.matterInfoSortName+"</td>"
                                        +"<td>"+value.matterInfoMatterNum+"</td>"
                                        +"<td>"+value.matterInfoFileDesc+"</td>"
                                        +"<td><input type='button' value="+value.matterInfoFileDesc+"></td>"
                                        +"</tr>";
                                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#matterTable tbody");
                                    //alert(key + ': ' + value.matterInfoSortName);

                                });

                                $("button").live("click",function(){
                                     var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                                     var rowIndex = row.index();
                                     alert(rowIndex);
                                });

                            }else{
                                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                .text('There was an error.').show(200);
                            }

                            $('#searchForm').show(200);

                            if (data.error === true)
                                $('#searchForm').hide(200);
                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $('#waiting').hide(200);
                            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                            .text('There was an error.').show(200);
                            $('#searchForm').show(200);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });


            });


        </script>

    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?  There are a few ways to do this and it will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you ask for the row index, there are users that have given you the answer. 
But, usually we need the id of the row, because the id belongs to an id in the database. 
In this case, you could use the id of the cell or the button itself.
Example:

```
  <table>
   <tr  id="Data1"><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td><input type="button" value="Data"/></td></tr>
    <tr  id="Data2"><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td><input type="button" value="Data"/></td></tr>
    <tr  id="Data3"><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td><input type="button" value="Data"/></td></tr>
    <tr  id="Data4"><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td><input type="button" value="Data"/></td></tr>
    </table>

    $("input[type=button]").live("click", function() {
       var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       var rowId = row.attr("id");
        alert(rowId);
    });
```

You have this here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/YD3xy/

Comment: I have updated my code, but will only work if you include the id in the tr. If not, you can choose the "index()" option.

Answer (score 2):

You can go from `this` (the clicked button) in the handler and use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the `<tr>` of the button then grab anything you want from there, for example:

```
$(".someButton").live("click", function() {
   var row = $(this).closest("tr");
   var rowIndex = row.index();
});
```

For a full list of "moving-around" functions like this, check out the [Tree Traversal section of the API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Thanks!It works fine on its own but i can't figure out how to make it work on the actually project. I am still in the learning stages of this.

Comment: What i have is that i am generating a table from a JSON reply by calling a REST request.What i want right now is that when i click on one of the buttons or a link associated with the rows, i want to fire another REST requests to get a much detailed  information . How would i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using...

```
$('.all_links').click(some_function)
```

So in that case, you can simply find it from inside `some_function` like so:

```
function some_function() {
    $(this).parents('tr'); // this will give you the link's row.
}
```

Comment: This would get *all* `<tr>` ancestors, if this were a nested table for instance.